# Hide element or create on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Which option is best:

- Have an element in the markup, hidden with CSS. If JS is enabled, show that element.
- Have no element in the markup and create it on the fly, if JS is enabled.

If the user doesn't have JS, I don't want a div to be shown. My question isn't how to code the different cases, it's which is the best and why.

**EDIT**:
When I say "best" I mean support your answer with why it's the best for you. Can be speed/semantics/etc. What I want is to be able to have a better look at the pros and cons of each one. Also the speed is hardly an issue because it's only one element so it would be like milliseconds.

For the first option, it's probably faster, but then we have unnecessary markup and CSS rules. Because if there is no JS, there would be no point in having the element at all, much less hiding it.

Now the second option, even though it might not be as fast, I keep the different parts separate and only really load what has to be loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Speed/performance, or semantics?

Comment: If you are only wanting to show the element if the user has javascript I would insert it into the dom as if you hide it with css you can get punished by search engines for doing so.  Also, people with who have css disabled (or some screen readers) will also have access to the content.  But this is only my opinion

Comment: @Pete, search engines are smart enough to ignore content hidden with `display: none`, they may punish you if there's a lot of content being pushed out of sight with `text-align` though. And of course, by "search engines" I mean "Google".

Comment: @jonnysooter Haven't you just listed the pros and cons yourself?

Comment: @Liam I want to know if there are any other reasons I didn't get from my research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM manipulations are the most expensive. Showing existing code is faster than injecting it.

Comment: Although that's true, performance in JavaScript is rarely an issue due to how much idle time the page typically has.

Comment: Also allows you to style your page without running the js everytime you want to style a particular element.

Comment: Also, it's uncommon that someone doesn't have JS, so the extra code would be used more often than not. So most loads would be calling a JS function, which would generate an element, then assign CSS rules to it... which is definitely less efficient then just showing a hidden div.